# Find the union and intersection of each of the following families or indexed?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For each natural number $n$, let $A_n =$ {$5n,5n+1,5n+2...,6n$}, and let $\mathcal A$  =  {  $A_n$: n ∈ N}.

My question for this problem is how does one approach this enigma. I understand that natural numbers are numbers {1,2,3,4,5...} and that you plug in n=1, and n=2. When you plug n=1 you get. {5,6,7,6}. n=2 gets you {10,11,12,12} . My question is when do you stop and how can you unionize all these numbers will a correct answer be {5,6,7,8,9,10,11..} since it goes to infinity also what about intersection will any of the numbers be the same I do not think so but this is what has got me confused.

Comment: You never stop. You unionize *all*.  But you are wrong about $A_1$.  You plug in 1 and you get {5,6} only (no 7 and 6 only once).  You plug in 2 you get $A_2$ = {10,11,12}.  Each $A_n$ will have n + 1 elements.  So the infinite union will be {5,6,10,11,12,15,16,17,18,21,22,23,24,.....} forever.  Can you write a general form for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three dots notation is not meant literally to always use the first terms mentioned, or the last two if they are mentioned. For example if $C(n)==\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ then $C(1)$ is not $\{1,2,1\}$ but instead it just means to stop when $n$ is reached, so $C(1)=\{1\},$ and $C(2)=\{1,2\}$ and so on. Mentioning terms just before the last one is also not automatically in the set, unless they finish the pattern.

In your example, using this idea, $A_1=\{5,6\}.$ And $A_2=\{10,11,12\}.$

If you now want to get the union of all the $A_n$ it seems it would not have $7$ in it, since for $n\ge 2$ the set $A_n$ starts at $5n \ge 5\cdot 2=10.$ You need to figure out which numbers are skipped. Eventually the sets $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ will start to overlap.

Comment: I figured out that A1: is {5,6} and A2 is {10..12}. First and last and what comes in the middle.

Comment: That's right. That's how the dots notation is generally used.